# How to match an OR expression without grouping it?

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing bind db files<sup>1</sup>, with lines similar<sup>2</sup> to

```
www.sales   1D IN   A   10.0.0.1
www.learning    1D IN   CNAME   something
www.it 1D IN    AAAA    1::0::whatever
```

I want to catch the first string (`www.sales` for instance), but only when there is an `A` or `CNAME` in the line.

I used (thanks to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vH7/1)) the `\s*(\S+).*(\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)` as the regex in my code:

```
with open(file) as f:
   db = f.read()
z = re.finditer(r"\s*(\S+).*(\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)", db)
z = [i.group(0) for i in z]
```

The result of this is

```
['    www.sales\t1D IN\tA\t', '\n    www.learning\t1D IN\tCNAME\t']
```

I have two problems with this result, which I do not understand:

1. why wasn't `www.sales` (to take the first case) matched on its own - but with the whole line described in the regex expression? the regex101 link above shows correct grouping.
2. how can I get rid of the second group? I still want to have the clause as a requirement (ie. to have eitheer `A` or `CNAME` in the line), but I am not interested in keeping the match

---

<sup>1</sup> I am aware of the `dns` module but for various reasons it does not meet my needs

<sup>2</sup> Note following the comments about the bind file format: yes I am aware that this bind fine is not correct. What I did is to copy/paste the source of this post when testing (so with spaces before the text - Markdown syntax) and ended up with such a file. I expanded my regex a bit to take this into account - the actual file is correct.

Comment: You mean [`(\S+).*\s(?:A|CNAME)\s`](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vH7/2) ?

Comment: You just need `i.group(1)` as the `www.sales` are in group 1.

Comment: Why do you have spaces before the names in your matches? A proper zone file should not have the lines indented, because indentation makes it a continuation line.

Comment: @Barmar: you are right, I added a comment in my question (footnote 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid creating a capturing group, use a non-capturing group, instead of `(...)` use `(?:...)`:

```
\s*(\S+).*(?:\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)
```

You are also grabbing the *whole matched line* with `.group(0)`. Take group 1 if you just want the first group from the match. You don't then need to match the initial whitespace either; you are not anchoring to the start of the line:

```
z = re.finditer(r"(\S+).*(?:\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)", db)
z = [i.group(1) for i in z]
```

Finally, with one group you could just use `re.findall()` to produce a list:

```
z = re.findall(r"(\S+).*(?:\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)", db)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> db = '''\
... www.sales   1D IN   A   10.0.0.1
... www.learning    1D IN   CNAME   something
... www.it 1D IN    AAAA    1::0::whatever
... '''
>>> re.findall(r"(\S+).*(?:\sA\s|\sCNAME\s)", db)
['www.sales', 'www.learning']
```

Rather than requiring whitespace around the `A` or `CNAME`, I'd anchor on word boundaries (`\b`), and look for a more limited set of permissible characters in the DNS name, and perhaps match the `IN` record class field as well:

```
r'([a-z0-9-.]+).*IN\s+(?:A|CNAME)\b'
```

Given your sample matches it looks like you have leading whitespace on each line of your input file; the actual BIND format disallows such whitespace.

Comment: You can't ignore initial whitespace. In DNS files, an indented line is a continuation of the previous line, and the first field is not the name.

Comment: I'm not sure why he has those leading spaces in his results, the lines in the zone file shouldn't be indented.

Comment: @Barmar: the sample matches show whitespace on each line at the start; I deliberately focused on the two issues in the question rather than on how correct their parsing of the BIND format is, but the sample they gave is not actually a valid BIND db file by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*(\S+)(?=.*?\b(?:A|CNAME)\b)
```

You can use this regex with `re.findall`.It will return a list of all captured strings.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/8

```
with open(file) as f:
   db = f.read()
print re.findall(r"^\s*(\S+)(?=.*?\b(?:A|CNAME)\b)",db,re.M)
```